# Hard disk become read-only frequently

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, read-only

I have an:
Laptop MYRIA MY8305GD, Intel® Celeron® N3350 2.4GHz, 13.3", 4GB, eMMC 32GB, Intel® HD Graphics 500.

I have installed last version of Ubuntu. Frequently after shutdown, or even in time when I am using it(writing simple text documents, browsing) the disk become readonly. Mounting a USB doesnt work. To fix this, I have to enter in recovery mode and using fsck -y on initfrms shell or using a Live USB check from gparted.

Now, sometimes I write larger documents and becomes frustrating.
Does exist other tools to fix this? or how can be solved?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows also (Dual Boot). This may be due to Windows fast boot. Disable it.

- Go to control Panel.
- Click Power Options.
- Click Choose what the power buttons do.
- Click Change settings that are currently unavailable.
- Uncheck Turn on fast startup (recommended).
- Click Save changes.
- Reboot

Comment: [@mikewhatever](https://askubuntu.com/users/20054/mikewhatever) Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all your data and change the disk if disk gives you enough time.
or if you do not have any important data then do this....
boot into live mode with any linux distro and use `e2fsck` .

```
sudo fdisk -l

sudo e2fsck -cpfv /dev/sdx
```

If any error is there asking not to use -a or -p then use

```
sudo e2fsck -cfvy /dev/sdx
```

It worked for me.